# HDMI signal showing as disconnected on Manjaro

Tags: xrandr, manjaro, multi-monitor, hdmi

I have been doing some research and it looks like my xrandr has some issues. The problem is I connect a HDMI monitor and it shows that is disconnected; somehow the port is not working properly. I'm using Manjaro.

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  48.01  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you see, it show as disconnected but the HDMI is connected.
Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto
```

Might fix your problem.